# Django views default values to templates

Tags: python, django, templates, view

Is there any way to pass a variable to all templates? For example I have a view which contains

```
render_to_response('page.html', dictionary, \
context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

and I would like to pass another variable to the template file which is not in the dictionary.

What's the aim? Let's say I need this variable in all the views (a couple of hundred), and simply I would love to pass this variable to the template file without touching the dictionary. By the way this variable is the result of a function, which has a parameter (request).

Is it doable?

Answer (score 6):

You'll want to write a custom [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors).

> A context processor has a very simple interface: It’s just a Python function that takes one argument, an `HttpRequest` object, and returns a dictionary that gets added to the template context. Each context processor *must* return a dictionary.
>
> Custom context processors can live anywhere in your code base. All Django cares about is that your custom context processors are pointed-to by your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting.

E.g.:

```
# in project/context_processors.py
def add_extra_variable(request):
    return {'extra': myfunction(request)}

# in settings.py:
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.core.context_processors.tz",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
    "project.context_processors.add_extra_variable"
 )
```

P.S.: if you use `render` instead of `render_to_response`, you don't need to pass the `RequestContext`.

```
render('page.html', dictionary)
```

Comment: Hi, it looks very simply and good, but i' ve default settings in the settings.py, and the `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS += ('project.context_processors.add_extra_variable',)` line breaks it, since it doesn' t exist. If i just simply equal it, then it' ll miss other things, like `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` . Any idea how could i resolve it?

Comment: Write them in full (edited my answer). (or `from django.conf.global_settings import TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`).